# looking for simple file "database" or file bundles in .net/c#

Tags: c#, .net, file, io, bundle

I am looking for a way to conveniently store image files or any kind of file, i.e. without just saving them somewhere in my project folders and keeping track of the files in some list/xml/something.

What I am looking for is something like a 'bundle', which I can easily access and query in c#/.net .. e.g. I can easily find out what files it contains.

The whole point is that I don't want to have a messy subfolder containing all those files and I want to avoid using the filesystem's querying, access and referencing methods.

Is there something out there you could recommend?

Comment: Would you elaborate on the purpose?  Is this for things that would normally fit into the project resources (icons, for example).  Or is it something of more dynamic nature?

Comment: Have you looked at System.IO.Packages?

Comment: It has to be dynamic; I want to be able to store and delete stuff at runtime. 

Anyway, Thanks! I now already have some nice pointers that will most likely help me. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn about resources in NET.
[Resources in Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f45fce5x%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Basically you can package resources to a dll and access them with a ResourceManager and a ResourceSet

Answer (score 0):

As George already said simply use this procedure:

- Right click on your project and select `Add - New Item`.
- From the dialog select `Resource File` and give that file a meaningful name.
- Double click on the file in the Solution Explorer
- Click on the `Add Resource` Button at the top and add the file(s) you want.

Now you can access these resources within your project by simply entering

```
var myResource = ResourceFileName.ResourceName
```

Within the Resource Editor you can also select an already selected resource and take a look into the Properties window. There you can change the FileType of the resource. This has an impact on the return type you'll get within your code (e.g. a binary file will be returned as `byte[]`, but a text file as `string`).